# IRC Bots Behind HTTP Proxies

Tags: linux, debian, irc

I'm trying to run an [IRC bot](http://inamidst.com/phenny/) in a Debian based server. Its behind a HTTP proxy, so, I need to 'export http_proxy' for normal usage. The problem I'm facing with the bot is that, as far as I know it doesn't support proxies. Anyway to make the HTTP proxy transparent to the program, something like tsocks?

Answer (score 1):

Try [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/). It behaves much like tsocks, but works better (on my laptop Opera worked with proxychains, but not with tsocks) and supports HTTP proxies. And, of course, your proxy should support and allow HTTP CONNECT method.